# In Spring boot convert String hexadecimal into ObjectId for aggreagation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have below code

```
@Override
public List<Snapshots> getData(final String modelId) {

    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("modelId").is(new ObjectId(modelId));
```

It doesn't return any results. It's equivalent to mongo query is below

```
db.Snapshots.aggregate([
      { 
     "$match":{ 
        "modelId":{ 
           "$oid":"5db6ce13f74c7f9f982f2598"
     }
  },
```

I know above will not work as mongo don't know what is "$oid is". If change it to ObjectID("5db6ce13f74c7f9f982f2598") then it works in mongo shell. Please let me know how can I pass this hexadecimal id from spring. This modelId is kind like a objectID of another collection and refereed as a foreign key in Snapshots collection.

Answer (score 0):

You either save (and search with) the hex string or the ObjectId

```
{
   ...,
   'modelId':{
        ObjectId('5db6ce13f74c7f9f982f2598')
    },
   ...
}
```

```
Criteria.where("modelId.$oid").is(new ObjectId(modelId))
```

or

```
{
   ...,
   'modelId': '5db6ce13f74c7f9f982f2598',
   ...
}
```

```
Criteria.where("modelId.$oid").is(modelId)
```

Have you tried spring-data-mongodb's @DBRef?